# encrypt and decrypt property file value in java

Tags: java, encryption

I am looking for a way to encrypt a password in a configuration file
that is being read by a Java program. Currently, I read-in the
password from the text file, but that leaves the password sitting right
out in the open if someone were to look at the config file.

I was thinking of building a simple class where user could type in
their desired password, get an encrypted version of the password, then
paste the encrypted version into the configuration text file. Then the
application would read encrypted password, decrypt the password back
into a string, and move on.

I am having trouble with the string-->encrytped bytes-->string
conversions.

I am using the built-in java security classes to implement this code.
Here is some sample test code:

```
    // Reads password from config file
String password = ScriptConfig.getString( "password" );

// Generate Key
KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
Key key = kg.generateKey();

// Create Encryption cipher
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "DES" );
cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key );

// Encrypt password
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( password.getBytes() );

// Create decryption cipher
cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key );
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal( encrypted );

// Convert byte[] to String
String decryptedString = new String(decrypted);

System.out.println("password: " + password);
System.out.println("encrypted: " + encrypted);
System.out.println("decrypted: " + decryptedString);

// Read encrypted string from config file
String encryptedPassword = ScriptConfig.getString( "encryptedPassword"
);

// Convert encryptedPassword string into byte[]
byte[] encryptedPasswordBytes = new byte[1024];
encryptedPasswordBytes = encryptedPassword.getBytes();

// Decrypt encrypted password from config file
byte[] decryptedPassword = cipher.doFinal( encryptedPasswordBytes );//error here

System.out.println("encryptedPassword: " + encryptedPassword);
System.out.println("decryptedPassword: " + decryptedPassword);


The config file has the following variables:
password=password
encryptedPassword=[B@2a4983


When I run the code, I get the following output:
password: passwd
encrypted: [B@2a4983
decrypted: passwd
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple
of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_h.b(DashoA12275)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_h.b(DashoA12275)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(Da shoA12275)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA12275)
at com.sapient.fbi.uid.TestEncryption.main(TestEncryp tion.java:4
```

Any help on the error, structure, or process I am using to do this
would be great. Thanks.

Comment: If your application is on the client's machine, it can be cracked and the decryption key discovered. Once that happens you may as well be using plaintext. The only way to really secure that workflow is to have the decryption take place on a secure server. What problem are you trying to solve that led you to try this? (Why do you need to store a password like that?)

Comment: I didnt want to store password in config file as plain text.

Comment: @user234194: You're missing the point. If you store the decryption key  on the client, it is not secure and can be decrypted by anyone with the client.

Comment: Ultimately, no this is not secure, but it's a link in the chain. The idea is that you don't want to make it trivially easy for anyone with access to the machine / filesystem to see what the DB password is, for example. If security is only based on people not seeing this configuration file, you have bigger problems :)

Answer (score -12, accepted):

A really simple solution would be to use Base64 encoding, see the code snippet below :-

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

...

private String encode(String str) {
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    str = new String(encoder.encodeBuffer(str.getBytes()));
    return str;
}

private String decode(String str) {
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    try {
        str = new String(decoder.decodeBuffer(str));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return str;
}

...
```

Comment: the use of classes from sun.misc makes this non-portable, though

Comment: why is it non-portable ? and in what way ?

Comment: using base64 encoding would prevent the property from being revealed to the naked eye, but once someone get a hold of the hash, couldn't they run it through a reverse base64 method?

Comment: @Haoest more specifically - it's not a Hash in the first place. At all.

Comment: Base64 is a storage format, not a hashing function, and certainly not a proper encryption scheme. It's also plainly visible to the naked eye (the fact that it was used)  in the "encoded" form.

Comment: dont use base64  never!

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at [Jasypt](http://jasypt.org). It has already done the heavy lifting for you. Specifically, the `org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor` and `org.jasypt.properties.PropertyValueEncryptionUtils` classes.

Create an encryptor:

```
SimplePBEConfig config = new SimplePBEConfig(); 
config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");
config.setKeyObtentionIterations(1000);
config.setPassword("propertiesFilePassword");

StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setConfig(config);
encryptor.initialize();
```

Then use `PropertyValueEncryptionUtils` to encrypt / decrypt values:

```
PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.encrypt(value, encryptor);
PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(encodedValue, encryptor)
```

Note the encoded value will start with `ENC(` and end with `)`, so it's easy to tell if a property from a file is encrypted.

Also, note that the password used for `config.setPassword()` is *not* the password you are encoding to store in the properties file. Instead, it is the password to encrypt / decrypt *the value* you are storing. What this password is and how to set it is up to you. I default to the fully qualified classname of whatever is reading the Properties file.

Finally, if you are using Spring, Jasypt has an `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class that you can use to load the properties file and use `${foo}` syntax in your Spring XML files to do variable substitution for things like DB passwords.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some helpers to encrypt or decrypt using AES in Java:

```
public static final String AES = "AES";

/**
 * Encrypt a value and generate a keyfile.
 * If the keyfile is not found, then a new one will be created.
 * 
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
public static String encrypt(String value, File keyFile)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    if (!keyFile.exists()) {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(CryptoUtils.AES);
        keyGen.init(128);
        SecretKey sk = keyGen.generateKey();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(keyFile);
        fw.write(byteArrayToHexString(sk.getEncoded()));
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }

    SecretKeySpec sks = getSecretKeySpec(keyFile);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CryptoUtils.AES);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks, cipher.getParameters());
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
    return byteArrayToHexString(encrypted);
}

/**
 * Decrypt a value.
 * 
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
public static String decrypt(String message, File keyFile)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    SecretKeySpec sks = getSecretKeySpec(keyFile);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CryptoUtils.AES);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexStringToByteArray(message));
    return new String(decrypted);
}

private static SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec(File keyFile)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    byte[] key = readKeyFile(keyFile);
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, CryptoUtils.AES);
    return sks;
}

private static byte[] readKeyFile(File keyFile)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(keyFile).useDelimiter("\\Z");
    String keyValue = scanner.next();
    scanner.close();
    return hexStringToByteArray(keyValue);
}

private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] b) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(b.length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        int v = b[i] & 0xff;
        if (v < 16) {
            sb.append('0');
        }
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
    }
    return sb.toString().toUpperCase();
}

private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        int index = i * 2;
        int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
        b[i] = (byte) v;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Just call the appropiate method.

Comment: Complete source is on code.google.com [here](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/android-openid/source/browse/trunk/CryptoUtils/src/CryptoUtils.java?r=29).

Answer (score 2):

> I am having trouble with the string-->encrytped bytes-->string conversions.

I'd stuff the byte array through a base64 en/decoder, this way you'll have to persist strings that contain nothing but chars within (a subset of) ASCII, which should limit your trouble. Have a look e.g. at [commons codecs](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) and replace your `new String(decrypted)` with a call to one of the static methods in the `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` class.

Besides that I think what you ultimately want to do is not strictly to "encrypt" the password but rather to store only a hash of the password, which was already discussed on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/suggestions-for-library-to-hash-passwords-in-java).