# Create ini file

Tags: java, file, ini

I wounder how to make .ini file in Java. I know how to make .txt file, but how to make .ini file I don't. For reading and wrting I use ini4j lib and I thnik it works good. First I make some directory because of saving some data from user, then I want to make file and I get error java.io.FileNotFoundException for codeline ini.load(new FileReader(INI_PATH)); , that means that my code doesn't make .ini file in codeline File newFile = new File(newPath+"connect.ini"); . Please help me!

My code is:

```
 String path =System.getProperty("user.home");
 dir = new File(path+"/ProjectName");
 String newPath=path+"/ProjectName";
 if(dir.exists()){
System.out.println("DIRECTORY EXISTS");
 }
 else{
     dir.mkdir();
 }
 newPath=newPath+"/";
 File newFile = new File(newPath+"connect.ini");
 INI_PATH = newFile.getAbsolutePath();
 System.out.println("INI_PATH "+INI_PATH);
 Wini ini = new Wini();
 ini.load(new FileReader(INI_PATH));

 ...SOME CODE FOR ADDUING PAIRS....
```

Comment: You can find your answer from this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193474/how-to-create-an-ini-file-to-store-some-settings-in-java

Comment: I have read this post at lest 3 times, it says about making properties class and so on and I don't understand what actualy means ".myappdir" in first answer, which is most helpfull for my problem...

Comment: THere, simple approach is given, if you want to save properties, then use properties file instead of INI file. ".myappdir" is the directory where properties file will be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a FileNotFoundException because the file does not exist on the disk, if you are trying to create the file in code use the following:

```
File newFile = new File(newPath+"connect.ini");
newFile.createNewFile();
```

the createNewFile() method on Java's File class will create a file if it doesn't exist, then you can feel free to use a FileReader or FileWriter to work with the newly created (but blank) file.

Comment: Ok this createNewFile is working, but now I have problems in line ini.store(); before that line I put some parameters like ini.put("DATABASE", "databasename","") and so on to save in ini file. The error is still FileNotFoundException. I have chechked that the file is in specified directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: We would need to see the relevant section of code before an answer for that issue specifically could be given.